# Is there a way to get the average of two arrays by using a single method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

All the research I've done suggests making a third array that contains both orginal arrays, and using that to get an average. I am new to programming, and our teacher likes making us search for answers in labs (not graded). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) e.g. `a.union(b).Average(x=>somthing meaningful)`

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: what does 'get the average of two arrays' mean?

Comment: Simply you do (sum of array1 + sum of array2)/(length of array1 + length of array2)

Comment: To flesh out @W3AVE's question - if you have an array containing [1,3] and another array containing [3,3], what would the average of the two arrays be? Would it be [2,3] - meaning the average of first elements of both arrays, then the average of the second elements of both arrays? Are the arrays numeric?

Comment: use `.Concat(...)` not `.Union(...)`

Comment: `int[] A = { 12, -22, 17, -55, 33, 44, 7, -9, 15, -6, -3, 18 };
  int[] B = { 77, -14, 42, 36, 16, -5, -8, 56, 11, 30, 25, 72 };`

Comment: I have 2 int[] arrays each with 12 elements. The teacher is asking us to figure out how to take all 24 elements and get an average from them via a method. Sorry for not specifying what kind of array it was sooner.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data1 = new[] { 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, };
var data2 = new[] { 4f, 4f, };

var ret1 = data1.Concat(data2).Average();
Console.WriteLine(ret1);
//2.666667
```

Comment: as a note if you use `.Union(...)` the answer will be `3` as duplicate values will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array for almost anthing, so that means "average of an array" is a meaningless request. What does that mean? Say I have an array of strings, what should be the average of it? If you mean it is an array of primitives like int, double ... then simply you can Concat and average them. ie:

```
int[] array1 = {2,5,6};
int[] array2 = {20,50,60};

double average = array1.Concat( array2 ).Average ();
```

Comment: Averaging the averages of different arrays doesn't give you the correct result when the arrays contain different amounts of items.

Comment: Your way of building the average for `[9,9,9]` and `[1]` would result in 5. It should be 7.

Comment: So the actual question he asked us is: ` // Define a method that takes two arrays of ints. The method is to    //compute the average of all the values in both arrays and return it. 
  // Call the method in main`. And my arrays look like this `int[] A = { 12, -22, 17, -55, 33, 44, 7, -9, 15, -6, -3, 18 };
            int[] B = { 77, -14, 42, 36, 16, -5, -8, 56, 11, 30, 25, 72 };` I'm keeping it simple as I just learned arrays earlier this week.

Comment: Wosi you are absolutely right. What was thinking, friday night :) Edited.